# java regex string matches and multiline delimited with new line

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a regex that will match multiline delmitied by new line and spaces?

The following code works for one multiline but does not work if the input
is

`String input = "A1234567890\nAAAAA\nwwwwwwww"`

By which I mean `matches()` is not true for the input.

Here is my code:

```
package patternreg;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class pattrenmatching {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "A1234567890\nAAAAA";   
    String regex = ".*[\\w\\s\\w+].*";   
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.MULTILINE); 
    Matcher m =p.matcher(input);

            if (m.matches()) {
       System.out.println("matches() found the pattern \"" 
             + "\" starting at index " 
             + " and ending at index ");
    } else {
       System.out.println("matches() found nothing");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like it works! give some more specific, what happens? what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Hi Bhushan, the matches should return matches foundthe pattern even if the input is delimited by newline suppose if the input is having multiple newline A1234567890\nAAAAA\ndddd\ndddd\nddd, matches returns matches() found nothing"

Comment: i copied and pasted your code and executed, i got this output: A1234567890  
AAAAA*  
matches() found the pattern "" starting at index  and ending at index

Answer (score 1):

You could also add the DOTALL flag to get it working:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Still matches does not return true if it is delimited by new line:

Comment: With String input = "A1234567890"; matches is true other wise if the input is "A1234567890/nddd" matches is not true

Comment: Adding the DOTALL flag along with the MULTILINE didn't resolve the issue for you?  `m.matches()` returns true for me if I compile the pattern with both flags `Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL`.  I could be misunderstanding your issue though...

Comment: Oh ya thanks mbockus it returns true. Thanks a lot I had used the wrong regex

Comment: No prob!  Can you do me a favor and mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that .* is greedy, so it's matching all the other '\n' in the string.

If you want to stick with the code above try: "[\S]*[\s]+".  Which means match zero or more non-whitespace chars followed by one or more whitespace chars.

fixed up code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "A1234567890\nAAAAA\nsdfasdf\nasdfasdf";
    String regex = "[\\S]*[\\s]+";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {

        System.out.println(input.substring(m.start(), m.end()) + "*");
    }

    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("matches() found the pattern \"" + "\" starting at index " + " and ending at index ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("matches() found nothing");
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

> A1234567890
>   * AAAAA
>   * sdfasdf
>   * matches() found nothing

Also, a pattern of

> `"([\\S]*[\\s]+)+([\\S])*"`

will match the entire output (matcher returns true) but messes up the token part of your code.